# How to change every 2nd and 3rd element in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Here is my dilemma, I have this code:

```
var fibs = [1, 2];
for (i = 0; i < (window.innerWidth / 50); i++) {
    if (fibs.length < 15) {
        var n = fibs[i] + fibs[i + 1];
        fibs.push(n);
    }
}
```

Which creates an array of the Fibonacci Sequence. I then copy the contents of fibs to a new array, `top`. What I'm having trouble with is that I need every 2nd and 3rd elements on top to be the inverse sign of `fibs`. ie. `top[0] = fibs[0]; top[1] = -fibs[1]; top[2] = -fibs[2]; top[3] = fibs[3]` I want to be able to do this programmatically because the lengths of the arrays will change based on the width of the screen.

Below is what I'm trying to use.

```
var top = [];
for (i = 0; i < fibs.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0 || i % 3 == 0) {
        top[i] = -(fibs[i]);
    } else {
        top[i] = fibs[i];
    }
}
```

What I get is `[-1, 2,-3, -5, -8, 13, -21, 34, -55, -89, -144, 233, -377, 610, -987]`, when what I'm looking for is `[-1, 2, 3, -5, -8, 13, 21, -34, -55, 89, 144, ... ]`.

Comment: As I said on Programmers, elaborate on "isn't working."

Comment: Please give the desired output combined with the actual output of what you are getting.   Additionally that seems like an odd requirement as i%2==0 || i%3==0 will result in a pattern 0,2,3,4,6,8,9,10,12 14,15,16...  Is that what was intended?  If so and the elements of fibs were [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1], top would be [-1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 -1] (assuming no typos)

Answer (score 0):

While this might not be the best way to do it, this ought to work:

```
var topp = [];
for (i = 0; i < fibs.length; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 1 || i % 3 == 2) {
        topp[i] = fibs[i] - (2 * fibs[i]);
    } else {
        topp[i] = fibs[i];
    }
}
```

The code is pretty self explanatory.

#### EDIT:

Thanks to @alexpods for the tip about the `top` keyword.

Thanks to @Scott Hunter for pointing out the logical error.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to throw in a bit more flexible (and readable) solution to your problem:

```
function fibonacci(length) {
    var out = [0, 1];
    for (i = 2; i < length; i++) {
        out[i] = out[i-1] + out[i-2];
    }
    return out;
}

function modifyValues(source, factors) {
    var out = [];
    for (i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        out[i] = source[i] * factors[i % factors.length];
    }
    return out;
}

fibs = fibonacci(15);
mod1 = modifyValues(fibs, [1,-1,-1]);
console.log(fibs, mod1);
```

> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377]
>   [0, -1, -1, 2, -3, -5, 8, -13, -21, 34, -55, -89, 144, -233, -377]

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want

```
if ( i%3==1 || i%3==2 ) {
```

Alternatively, you could use

```
if ( i%3 ) { // will be treated as true as long as i%3 != 0
```